# How to write the Dockerfile for an IntelliJ project with multiple repositories?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I have a simple server-client Java application, in which the client can connect to the server and send/receive messages. The application is a project built with IntelliJ containing multiple repositories and Java files. I need to run the application on Docker but have no idea on how to build the image.

Currently, I can run the application locally on my machine by simply using 'compile' and 'build' option on IntelliJ IDEA but don't know how to package it into a Docker image.

I just recently started using IntelliJ and Docker so I do not have much experience with either of the two. As of yet I have only managed to Dockerize a simple HelloWorld application. Not sure if this matters, but my experience in Java is also negligible. The purpose of this task is to learn Docker, not Java.

I used the following Dockerfile for my HelloWorld application which was very straightforward as it had only one file inside a single folder.

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /var/www/java  
WORKDIR /var/www/java  
RUN javac HelloWorld.java  
CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
```

I want to know to know how I can do the same for my entire project. For context, there are 3 files inside the *src* folder for my server application: "Main.java", "Server.java" and "ServerThread". I need to run the server application in one container, and the client application in a separate one. Should the Dockerfile be built inside the src folder or at the root folder. How different should it be than the Dockerfile for a simple HelloWorld application? What file(s) should I be using the `run` command with?

I am overwhelmed with this since it's my first time working with Docker and big applications that need repositories.

Comment: Thank you for response! No, my client and server will be built into separate images/containers.

Comment: Sounds like a good chance to split into 2 intellij projects, each with its own dockerfile. Multiple repositories for the one intellij project sounds overcomplicated to me.

Comment: @halfer I will run the client and server containers on the same machine, but eventually would want to make them online.

Comment: @vikingsteve the server and client projects are already 2 separate IntelliJ projects. What I meant was they further contain more folders. My description may have been a little misleading here. There is one src folder containing 3 files as stated above. Other than that there is are folders called _.idea_ and  _out_ which contains the class files.

Answer (score -1):

### Copying files into containers

Firstly, the `WORKDIR` should generally appear before `COPY` operations. This sets the default location of files in the Docker image.

However, in your example, it does not affect the `COPY`, since there you are specifying an explicit container target directory. That said, it does affect your subsequent `javac` command, since there is no fully-qualified directory name here.

In your new example, you could do something like this:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/java  
COPY src src
```

This will copy all of the contents of `src` in your host's directory to `/var/www/java/src` in the image.

That should work as a bare minimum. Dockerfiles tend to be built incrementally, so once you get one thing working, you can then work on another thing. Don't try to do everything at once.

### Docker Compose

You've indicated that you want to spin up a server and a client in separate containers. To do that, you can use Docker Compose. This uses a simple YAML config file. In this example, one has a Dockerfile and one uses an existing image:

```
version: "2"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - BITBUCKET_PRIVATE_KEY
  listener:
    image: listener
```

The great thing with DC is that each container is automatically put on a virtual network - `client` will see a machine called `listener` (and vice versa). So the client can connect to `http://listener:port`.

### Fetching repos

At some point you may want to fetch your Java files from a version control system, so you can build your container under continuous integration. To do that, you will need to inject a private key, and then pull from Git etc; this can be done using a Docker volume or an environment variable (if you are interested in this, then it is probably worth asking that as a separate question, assuming it has not already been asked).